# Conflicting Answers from Marketing Test: Both Answers are Statistically Significant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

I'm running a marketing test comparing banner A against banner B against banner C.  Each banner received >10million exposures and based on response rate we concluded early in the test that banners B and C were both beating banner A.  However, after the test ran longer we analyzed the results and it now appears that banner A is our #2 performing banner and banner B has fallen to the bottom.  These latest results are also statistically significant.

My first instinct is that something must have changed structurally about the test for this to occur.  For example, I thought perhaps the demographics of the exposed audience shifted causing a different outcome.  But so far there appears to be no structural change.  With all of that as context, can someone please explain how you would approach interpreting these results? Would you trust the early findings or the recent findings? Am I correct to believe that the fact that the late findings contradict the early findings is indicative of something changing structurally about the test? After all, from a statistical standpoint isn't it highly unlikely for the early results to change with continued exposure of the ads all things being equal.  That's why we run the test for statistical significance.

I greatly appreciate any explanation or advice someone might be able to offer.

Comment: Sometimes weird stuff (even statistically significantly weird stuff) happens. Indeed, if p = .05 exactly, stuff that weird will happen 5 times in 100. That's not rare. 

Instead of focusing on p-values and whether they changed in various ways, I'd suggest focusing on effect size. With your hug sample, almost any effect size will be significant. However, it may not be of any practical importance.

Comment: Perhaps you might tell us a bit more about your situation. For example, do you think the hits are all or mostly first time hits or do you think most or many of the hits are repeat hits?  Is there any logical relationship between the pages A, B and C?  For example, is there any reason to visit page B after you digest the information in page A or C?  Are the pages linked?  For example, can you get from page A to B or to C?

Comment: Hi Joel, these are banners not pages.  All three are getting rotated equally across what is supposed to be a common pool of advertising impressions.

Comment: Peter, thank you for the insightful comment.  If you'd like to submit it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.  The votes from the community appear to agree.

Comment: You will be interested in this chapter http://www.statisticsdonewrong.com/regression.html. At least read the top section.